# NoClassDefFoundError while using SAP JCo in maven Sprinboot Application SAP CF

Tags: spring-boot-maven-plugin, sap-cloud-sdk, sapjco3, sap-cloud-foundry

​I am getting below error while trying to use sapjco3 in my Springboot application. I am deploying my application to SAP Cloud foundry environment packaging as war file with tomee7 TARGET_RUNTIME

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sap/conn/jco/JCo : cannot initialize class because prior initialization attempt failed]","level":"ERROR"

while adding the dependency from maven it is packaging the sapjco jar with following name and getting below error

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: JCo initialization failed with java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sapjco3 in java.library.path:[/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64, /usr/lib64, /lib64, /lib, /usr/lib] and in system

[image]

[https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/bapi-and-rfc/overview]

I have packaged the springboot as war instead of jar to resolve the sapjco dependency

https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/guides/spring-boot-war-deployment

Answer (score 1):

Change the scope of the dependency to provided as described in the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/docs/connectivity/sap-btp-connectivity-cf/on-premise-develop-sample-web-application#loio7808d1d32c994a9e860ab342e2188763__Include). SAP Java buildpack already includes a JCo runtime fitting to the Cloud Foundry environment. (credit to Markus who answered this originally [here](https://answers.sap.com/questions/13880767/noclassdeffounderror-while-using-sapjco-in-maven-s-1.html)).

For more information on how to manage dependencies provided by the SAP Java Buildpack please refer to the dedicated [guide here](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/guides/manage-dependencies#notes-on-the-sap-java-buildpack).